# N1QL convert timezone into date,Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to convert `2015-10-29T16:15:11.000Z` in to `2015-10-29` Date in N1QL query.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options here. The simplest way works if you can tolerate an ISO 8601 formatted time and uses the `DATE_TRUNC_STR(expression, part)` Date function:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC_STR(date_time, "day") AS new_date FROM bucket
```

The result for such a query (using `2015-10-29T16:15:11.000Z` as `date_time`) is:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "new_date": "2015-10-29T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can parse out the individual parts using the `DATE_PART_STR(expression, part)` function with the `TOSTRING(expression)` function with String concatenation (`||`):

```
SELECT TOSTRING(DATE_PART_STR(date_time, "year")) || "-" || TOSTRING(DATE_PART_STR(date_time, "month")) || "-" || TOSTRING(DATE_PART_STR(date_time, "day")) AS new_date FROM bucket
```

The result:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "new_date": "2015-10-29"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Reference:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html

Comment: You asked specifically how to convert a date in N1QL, hence my response. If you tried something that isn't working, can you add that information to your question?

Comment: You can also use SUBSTR(date_time, 0, 10), if you don't care about timezone. Don't appreciate the "bullshit" comment when people are trying to help.